# Regex to find integer or decimal from a string in java in a single group?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying `(\d+|\d+\.\d+)` on this sample string:

```
Oats     124   0.99        V    1.65
```

but it is giving me decimal number in different groups when I am using pattern matcher classes in Java.

I want my answers in a single group.

Comment: Please post actual code. Thanks.

Comment: @Adam I am using (\d+|\d+.\d+) as my regex on the input mentioned above.

Comment: Please paste the output that you are expecting.

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org/ ...

Comment: `\d+|\d+.\d+` will not work as you want because before regex will try to test if string is match for `\d+.\d+` it will first test for `\d+`. It happenes because pattern is being redden from left to right (parts from left have higher precedence than ones from right). Same rule applies for `fo|foo` regex. It will never be able to match `foo` because it first two characters of `foo` will be matched by `fo`. To solve this problem you could change order of `OR` (`|`) arguments (subregexes) to first thy to match `\d+\.\d+` instead if `\d+`, so try with `\d+\.\d+|\d+`.

Answer (score 19):

You don't need to have a separate patterns for integer and floating point numbers. Just make the decimal part as optional and you could get both type of numbers from a single group.

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Use the above pattern and get the numbers from group index 1.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lJ4lF9/1)

**Code:**

```
String s = "Oats     124   0.99        V    1.65";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
124
0.99
1.65
```

**Pattern explanation:**

- `()` [capturing group .](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- `\d+` matches one or more digits.
- `(?:)` [Non-capturing group.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Matches a dot and the following one or more digits. `?` after the non-capturing group makes the whole non-capturing group as optional.

**OR**

Your regex will also work only if you change the order of the patterns.

```
(\d+\.\d+|\d+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lJ4lF9/2)

Comment: is it possible to capture a double without a leading 0? i.e. ".99" instead of 0.99?

Comment: ya, why not? `(?<=\\s|^)\\.\\d+(?=\\s|$)`

Comment: To Parse negative number you can use (-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?

Edit:
\d+ match 1 or more digit
(?: non capturing group (optional)
   \. '.' character
   \d+ 1 or more digit
)?  Close non capturing group
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Can you please elaborate in just plain english why this is working and other not?

Answer (score 0):

Question not entirely clear, but the first problem I see is . is a magic character in regex meaning any character. You need to escape it with as . There are lots of regex cheat sheets out there, for example [JavaScript Regex Cheatsheet](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/javascript)

```
(\d+|\d+\.\d+)
```

Comment: this only returns an integer