# regex match exclamation points java

Tags: java, regex

I'm very new to regex and i'm struggling with a tiny project which can really help in my project. I want to know how to count groups of (consecutive)sequence of exclamation point. For instance lets consider the following string

```
String s = "OMG!!!, i love Computers !!!! and this !!! is really good!"
```

the count here should return 3. I tried the following, but it's nothing like what i want
public static int exclamation(String list) throws Exception{

```
String[] words = (list.split("\\s+"));
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*?(!!)*\\b");
int count = 0;
for(String s:words)
{       
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);       
    if(pattern.matcher(s) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(s);

    }
}

return count;
```

}

Comment: Use back-reference. [`(!)\1+`](https://regex101.com/r/fV3kT6/1)

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj the print function there is meant to see if i'm actually matching the right thing by trying to print it, but all it does is printing plain words (i'm testing this on a huge data set), not sure if it ignores the punctuation and just print the word before that, which is totally insane obviously

Comment: @Tushar seems to have the right answer but i can't print those exclamation marks to see if i'm matching them correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex won't print any ! mark because of `\b`. Your regex expects a word character to be present next to `!`, but in real there isn't a word character following `!` but a non-word character space.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*?(!{2,})");
```

or

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("!{2,}");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rT3wX3/1)

Comment: It doesn't seems to be valid in JAVA :(, i'm trying to fix it

Comment: It's the right regex. but i still can't count how many are in the string, i changed the `print` and increased the counter after each match but it gave me so numbers that are not even close to be right

Comment: did you want to check for how many ! exists on a string? Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25707792/3297613

Comment: yes it counts each one individually. For instance for the above string, the function returns 11

Comment: I fixed it THANKSS