# Setting up regex in Pattern object for java string

Tags: java, regex, string

Am trying to get all matches in a java string. The matches must be bases and powers in a math equation. As you know, bases and powers could be negative and decimals as well. I have the pattern, regex and matcher set up. It looks something like this, but it is not giving me what I expect. I guided myself by this post here on StackOverflow **[Regex to find integer or decimal from a string in java in a single group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707779/regex-to-find-integer-or-decimal-from-a-string-in-java-in-a-single-group)**

**Am really just interested in capturing powers that have negative exponents both integers and non-integers.**

Well here is my code:

```
String ss = "2.5(4x+3)-2.548^-3.654=-14^-2.545";
String regex = "(\\d^+(?:\\d+)?)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(ss);

while(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Wiwi the cat: "+m.group(1));
    }
```

The output of this code is nothing. Any ideas or suggestions would be great.

thanks

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: expected output here would be : 2.548^-3.654  AND ALSO: -14^-2.545 @Baby

Comment: this might be ugly but just try it `(\-?\d+\.\-?\d+\.?\^\-?\d+\.?\d+)|(-?\d+\.?\^\-?\d+\.?\d+)`

Comment: Hey thanks.. lets see @Baby

Comment: nothing happened @Baby

Comment: you need to escape the backslashes. see [**Demo here**](http://ideone.com/Qmwq1R)

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is this character: `^`. It means "start of input", so your regex can't match anything.

You must *escape* it `\^` so it becomes a literal.

I also fixed the rest of your regex:

```
String regex = "-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?(\\^-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?)?";
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/lDx0eW9qCC).

And use

```
match.group(); // the whole match
```

Comment: shouldn't I place parentheses around the regex so its taken as a group? @Bohemian

Comment: your code is giving me also 4 and 3 , which appear in the string like this:  4x + 3  , I only need the exponents that are negative with their bases and the ^ symbol  @Bohemian

Comment: Thanks for the tips.. I will only have to sort each substring returned by the matcher and keep the ones that contain the ^ symbol, discard the rest @Bohemian

Comment: @i_o no need to group the whole expression. That's `group(0)`, or just `.group()`

Comment: thanks for the tips again.. The regex works, not as intended, but it helped me find the solution with a few tweaks to the matching substrings. @Bohemian

Comment: @i_o do you want `"4x+3"` to be one whole match? If so, what can `"x"` be?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: replaced `[0123456789]` with `(\\d)`

EDIT EDIT: added context for OP

### Answer

Here's a pattern that should match what you need:

```
-?(\\d)+(\\.(\\d)+)?\\^-?(\\d)+(\\.(\\d)+)?
```

### Explanation

`-?` - zero or one minus symbols

`(\\d)+` - one or more digits

`(\\.(\\d)+)?` - (optional) a decimal point, followed by one or more digits

`\\^` - one caret symbol

---

Using this on your input with `String.replace(pattern, "[FOUND]")` produced:

```
"2.5(4x+3)[FOUND]=[FOUND]"
```

---

In the context of your answer, simply replace your `regex` with the one I posted, and use `m.group()` instead of `m.group(1)`.

```
String ss = "2.5(4x+3)-2.548^-3.654=-14^-2.545";
String regex = "-?(\\d)+(\\.(\\d)+)?\\^-?(\\d)+(\\.(\\d)+)?";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(ss);

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Wiwi the cat: " + m.group());
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: it doesn't match what am looking for....what's the purpose of the ? symbol @Archmage

Comment: The `?` symbol matches zero or one of the preceding expression. Can you give me the data you're using the regex on so I can check on my end? The data in your question worked perfectly with my answer...

Comment: it seems like your code will match the pattern, however I need to retrieve it for further processing. That's why I use the while loop and m.find() to find all occurrences of the matching substrings. @Archmage

Comment: ...So substitute my pattern for yours and use it in whatever matching context you like? A pattern is a pattern is a pattern, it exists outside of implementation. That's up to you.

Comment: well its possible.. could you try to see if you can get the substrings with the method indexOf(pattern) that way all those substrings could be retrieved for further processing. I am trying to tweak some other pattern and I think am getting close to the answer. @Archmage

Comment: I tried the example you gave me. But I get only one exponent power not both of them @Archmage

Comment: @i_o I don't know what to tell you; I've just run the code again and it prints both. Unless you provide me with something more substantial than "it doesn't work", I can't help you further than I already have.